# How do I increment and decrement a static variable when objects are created and destroyed using constructors and destructors in C++?

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

I have an Owner class that stores information about ownership.
For some needs I need to know how many owners were created in total so I created a static variable amountOfOwners inside the Owner class. In the constructor I increase the amountOfOwners and in the destructor I decrease it. I create three owners but in static variable 0.

class Owner:

```
class Owner {

    std::string fullname;
    std::string inn;
    std::vector<Property*> properties;
    int amountOfProperty;
  
public:

    static int amountOfOwners;

    Owner(const std::string& fullname, const std::string& inn);
    ~Owner();

    void addProperty(Property *p);
    void removeProperty(const Property* p);

};


Owner::Owner(const std::string& fullname, const std::string& inn) {
    this->fullname = fullname;
    this->inn = inn;
    amountOfProperty = 0;
    amountOfOwners++;
}

Owner::~Owner() {

    amountOfOwners--;
}

void Owner::addProperty(Property* p) {

    properties.push_back(p);
    amountOfProperty++;

}

void Owner::removeProperty(const Property* property) {

    auto it = std::find(properties.begin(), properties.end(), property);
    if (it != properties.end()) {
        properties.erase(it);
        amountOfProperty--;
    }
}


}
```

main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Property.h"
#include "Appartment.h"
#include "Car.h"
#include "CountryHouse.h"
#include "Owner.h"

using namespace std;

int Owner::amountOfOwners = 0;

int main()
{
    std::vector<Owner> owners;
    char choice;

    Owner owner1("John Doe", "123456789012");
    owner1.addProperty(new Appartment(100000, 80));
    owner1.addProperty(new Car(50000, 200));
    owner1.addProperty(new CountryHouse(200000, 50));

    Owner owner2("Jane Smith", "987654321098");
    owner2.addProperty(new Appartment(150000, 100));
    owner2.addProperty(new Car(60000, 250));
    owner2.addProperty(new CountryHouse(300000, 70));

    Owner owner3("Mike Johnson", "456789012345");
    owner3.addProperty(new Appartment(120000, 90));
    owner3.addProperty(new Car(55000, 220));
    owner3.addProperty(new CountryHouse(250000, 60));

    owners.push_back(owner1);
    owners.push_back(owner2);
    owners.push_back(owner3);

    cout << Owner::amountOfOwners;
    return 0;
```

Static variable amountOfOwners equal to 0

Comment: Probably need a copy constructor.

Comment: This code also leaks memory, the allocated properties are not properly released. Consider wrapping those so they're properly managed.

Comment: Unable to compile the shown code. Please post a [mcve], so we can see it: *Static variable amountOfOwners equal to 0* after the program run.

Comment: `owners` is deleted before the `cout`put, hence the `Owner`s too. Use a debugger and breakpoints,  or logging.

Comment: @JoopEggen — `owners` gets destroyed (not deleted) at the closing brace in `main`, i.e., after the output.

Comment: Add a copy constructor that increments the counter. `std::vector` shuffles things around when you add elements, and that uses the copy constructor and the destructor. With the default copy constructor the new objects don’t get counted, but the destructors of the copied objects decrement the count.

Comment: Style note: use member initialization lists rather than assigning to `this->member` in the body of your constructor(s).

Comment: The Rule of Three applies to any resource, even one as simple as a counter.

Answer (score 0):

Probably better to use a separate class that is responsible for counting the number of instances.  That is a *single responsibility principle*, and will keep the other classes less cluttered with multiple responsibilities.

Here's an example that keeps track of how many instances were created ever, how many are alive at the moment, most that have been alive at one time, and how many have been destroyed.

And the same `Highwater` "mixin" can be used to keep track of as many classes as you care about.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using std::map;
using std::ostream;
using std::cout;
using std::size_t;
using std::string;

namespace {

struct HighwaterEntry {
    size_t created{};
    size_t alive{};
    size_t most_alive{};
    size_t destroyed{};
};


static map<string, HighwaterEntry> HighwaterDB;

void print_highwater(map<string, HighwaterEntry> const& m = HighwaterDB, ostream& out = cout) {
    for (auto&& x : m) {
        out << x.first
            << ": created:" << x.second.created
            << " alive:" << x.second.alive
            << " most_alive:" << x.second.most_alive
            << " destroyed:" << x.second.destroyed
            << "\n";
    }
}

template <typename CRTP>
struct Highwater {
    Highwater() noexcept { inc(); }
    Highwater(Highwater const&) noexcept { inc(); }
    Highwater(Highwater&&) noexcept { inc(); }
    auto operator=(Highwater const&) noexcept -> Highwater& { return *this; }
    auto operator=(Highwater&&) noexcept -> Highwater& { return *this; }
    ~Highwater() { dec(); }

private:
    void inc() noexcept {
        auto key = typeid(CRTP).name();
        auto& entry = HighwaterDB[key];
        ++entry.created;
        ++entry.alive;
        if (entry.alive > entry.most_alive) entry.most_alive = entry.alive;
    }

    void dec() noexcept {
        auto key = typeid(CRTP).name();
        auto& entry = HighwaterDB[key];
        --entry.alive;
        ++entry.destroyed;
    }
};

struct Property {};

class Owner : public Highwater<Owner> {

    std::string fullname;
    std::string inn;
    std::vector<Property*> properties;
    int amountOfProperty;

public:

    static int amountOfOwners;

    Owner(const std::string& fullname, const std::string& inn);
    ~Owner();

    void addProperty(Property *p);
    void removeProperty(const Property* p);

};


Owner::Owner(const std::string& fullname_, const std::string& inn_) {
    fullname = fullname_;
    inn = inn_;
    amountOfProperty = 0;
    amountOfOwners++;
}

Owner::~Owner() {

    amountOfOwners--;
}

void Owner::addProperty(Property* p) {

    properties.push_back(p);
    amountOfProperty++;

}

void Owner::removeProperty(const Property* property) {

    auto it = std::find(properties.begin(), properties.end(), property);
    if (it != properties.end()) {
        properties.erase(it);
        amountOfProperty--;
    }
}

int Owner::amountOfOwners = 0;

} // anon

int main() {
    std::vector<Owner> owners;
    char choice;

    Owner owner1("John Doe", "123456789012");
    //owner1.addProperty(new Appartment(100000, 80));
    //owner1.addProperty(new Car(50000, 200));
    //owner1.addProperty(new CountryHouse(200000, 50));

    Owner owner2("Jane Smith", "987654321098");
    //owner2.addProperty(new Appartment(150000, 100));
    //owner2.addProperty(new Car(60000, 250));
    //owner2.addProperty(new CountryHouse(300000, 70));

    Owner owner3("Mike Johnson", "456789012345");
    //owner3.addProperty(new Appartment(120000, 90));
    //owner3.addProperty(new Car(55000, 220));
    //owner3.addProperty(new CountryHouse(250000, 60));

    owners.push_back(owner1);
    owners.push_back(owner2);
    owners.push_back(owner3);

    cout << Owner::amountOfOwners << "\n";
    print_highwater();
}
```